# Compose ModalBottomSheetLayout inside full screen Dialog always visible on system navigation panel

Tags: android, layout, dialog, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I have screen with full sized Dialog() and a button which open ModalBottomSheet, I had no problems with this in usual screens, but here the top of the sheet is always visible in inactive (hidden) state) like some artifact half cover the action bar.
[image]

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
    properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)
) {
    ModalBottomSheetLayout(
        //...
    ) {
        Scaffold(
            modifier = modifier,
            topBar = {}
        ) { innerPadding ->
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to move Dialog() inside ModalBottomSheetLayout but in this case, as I understand, the ModalBottomSheet opened/closed behind dialog and not visible to the user.
Please, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overcome this issue I removed Dialog() at all, left Scaffold on the top. The behavior of the screen and functionality is not affected. All works correct.